# Access denied when connecting to an AWS MySql database from an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've just set up a MySQL database in AWS, however every time I try to connect programmatically I get an access denied exception. Connecting through MySQL Workbench works absolutely fine.

I've added my IP address to the Inbound Rules in AWS (without it, Workbench can't connect so it's definitely set up somewhat correctly) and even added a rule to allow all IP addresses for all traffic:

[image: Allow all rule]

This is a bare minimum example of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

MySqlConnection connection = new(CONNECTION_STRING);
connection.Open();
```

which throws the exception on `connection.Open()`.

Connection string:

```
Server=aa11sgbkk911b5j.cevakqici96g.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Database=ebdb;Uid=username;Pwd=password;
```

The exact exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Authentication to host 'aa11sgbkk911b5j.cevakqici96g.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' for user 'username' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'burntorangeadmin'@'cpc150000-brnt4-2-0-cust812.5-2.cable.virginm.net' (using password: YES)
  Source=MySql.Data
  ...
```

Does anyone have any idea why I can't connect?

Comment: Have you enabled privileges for your user?

Comment: AWS had additional authentication beyond a connection string.  Database, for example, can be locked down so that only specific compute resources are able to connect to them.  This article might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

Answer (score 2):

I originally had the database coupled to an Elastic Beanstalk instance, and after creating a new one separately everything worked as expected.

So still no actual solution to why it wasn't working in the first place, but decoupling has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have granted the appropriate privileges to the user account

Eg.

```
CREATE USER 'cdcuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY "cdcpwd";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'cdcuser'@'%' ;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: It looks like my user does have all privileges, I tried the `GRANT` anyway, but still getting the same error. I'm using the same user for the MySQL Workbench and obviously everything is fine for that. Very strange.

Comment: Ah glad you got it sorted. Apologies for the unhelpful advice

Comment: Always worth trying something! I am still in the dark about what caused the issue in the first place, but maybe this is best left alone!!